# Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP and I got the following error:

```
Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: C:\xampp\htdocs\project\app\Controller\TripsController.php    
Line: 12
```

Tripscontroller.php code:

```
<?php 

class TripsController extends AppController{         

    public $name= 'Trip';

    public function index($City=null){ 
        $trips = $this->Trip->find('all');
        $this->set('trips',$trips);

        $cities = $this->Trip->City->find('all');        
        $this->set('cities',$cities); 
    }
}
```

I've already associated the two objects inside "trips.php":

```
<?php
class Trip extends AppModel
{
    public $name= 'Trip';
    public $belongsTo= array('City');
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to add a `__construct ()` function and the give `$this`

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#file-and-class-name-conventions , http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::$name

Comment: What is "trips.php"?  That does not follow any convention.

Answer (score 0):

HEHA :) Inside  controller

```
public $name= 'Trips';
```

is correct U had `Trip`  , Remember controller uses plural name.

Also model file name => `Trip.php`

Answer (score -1):

Try:-

> public $uses = array( 'Trip' );
>   
>   in your controller

Comment: Dude , trip is already connected in relationship as per OP. check belongs to in question. So no need to Implicitely use `public $uses`